# Aerospike charset utf8 setting

Tags: go, utf-8, aerospike

I am inserting  a record in aerospike. Everything is working fine on my local environment. However, on the staging environment, UTF-8 characters are not being stored correctly.

> aql> select msg from test.msges
>
> LIST('["{"message_id":"kxwFZHVBKj","title":"à¸„à¸³à¸–à¸²à¸¡à¹„à¸”à¹‰à¸£à¸±à¸šà¸à¸²à¸£à¸•à¸­à¸šà¸à¸¥à¸±à¸šà¹à¸¥à¹‰à¸§!","actions":
> |
> +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 1 row in set (0.038 secs)

Also, this is being done using a golang clinet which is pretty UTF-8 safe i.e. no problems of byte-to-string or string-to-byte conversions and this works fine on local, hence
I am assuming this has something to do with aerospike configuration or version. The aerospike version on my local is 3.14.1.1 and on staging is 3.9.1.1.

One more thing I noticed based on the c-client comments coming on this post is that on my local machine I get the following aql version:

> Aerospike Query Client Version 3.13.0.1 C Client Version 4.1.6

But on the remote I have the following:

> Aerospike Query Client Version 3.9.1.2

The C-client version is missing !

Anyone can help what configuration (or whatever) am I missing here ?

Comment: It looks like utf-8 that is being output as a single character encoding.

Comment: What's your locale? I.e. what `locale` prints there?

Comment: LANG=
LC_CTYPE=POSIX
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=

Comment: on my local machine the locale is en_US.utf-8. I thought this could be the problem. But I changed my locale on local machine and was hoping I would reproduce the problem locally but still the characters were fine :(

Comment: aql is a C-application that runs the C client underneath. Did you check if this is not an aql bug by retrieving msg bin through your golang client?

Comment: @pgupta yes. I got this problem with my golang client. That's when I logged in to the remote machine and tried the aql (which also gave the same result). Also, if it was an aql bug, it wouldn't have worked on my local machine right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

aql is a tool written in c-client. In c-client, the application is expected to handle utf-8 encoding as there is no "string" datatype similar to newer generation languages that support multibyte utf-8 characters. The application reading data should have prior knowledge that the data is indeed written with utf-8 encoding to handle that. aql cannot determine that as it is a generic tool. So, it ends up printing each byte as a character.

Comment: In that case, why I see the multibyte characters correctly on my local machine ?

Comment: Can you show how the same query comes out in your local machine

Comment: The result contains proper characters like ามได้รับการต